# Using C array to store structs and then trying to read the array using pointer to the first element

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

So I'm using an array to store sructs (struct is Path). Defined as such:

```
Path **array = malloc(items * sizeof(Path *));
```

Then each element is alloc'd:

```
for (i=0;i<items;i++) 
{
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Path *));
}
```

Later in the program variables are updated as such:

```
Path *path = array[id];
path->next_hop=-1;
path->weight=INT_MAX;
```

I then have a separate function to print the values of the array, taking the pointer to the first item in the array (array[0]) and the size of array as parameters, declared as such:

```
void PrintTable(Path *paths, int n)
{
    if(paths == NULL || n <= 0)
        return;
    printf("%s %8s %8s\n", "Net ID", "Weight", "Next Hop");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Path *p = paths + i;
        printf("%d %8.2f %8d\n", vertices[i],p->weight, p->next_hop);
    }

}
```

When I was debugging I noticed that the stuct pointers seem to be in memory addresses with locations 0x000000000020 apart while in the loop the memory addresses being read are 0x000000000010 apart. Therefore by making this change:

```
Path *p = paths + i;
```

to

```
Path *p = paths + (2 * i);
```

It seems to work. Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't `Path *paths` be `Path *paths[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of pointers to `Path`, not an array of `Path`. So the argument to `PrintTable` should be `Path **paths` or `Path *paths[]`, not `Path *paths`.

Then you can simply index it rather than using pointer arithmetic in the loop.

```
void PrintTable(Path *paths[], int n)
{
    if(paths == NULL || n <= 0)
        return;
    printf("%s %8s %8s\n", "Net ID", "Weight", "Next Hop");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %8.2f %8d\n", vertices[i], paths[i]->weight, paths[i]->next_hop);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not overlook `array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Path *));`, where the type of `array[i]` is `Path *`, so the size should be of `*array[i]` or `Path`.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do it without modifying the PrintTable function? (I am not allowed to change it)

Comment: @Nat569On You could change your array to be `Path *array` instead of `Path **array`.

Comment: @Barmar but isn't that for a single struct pointer, not an array of struct pointers?

Comment: Why use an array of struct pointers instead of an array of structs? That's what `PrintTable` expects. If you don't want to modify the `PrintTable` function, you have to make the data match what it expects.

Comment: @Nat569On `Path *array = malloc(items * sizeof(Path));` will allocate an array of 'items' Paths, which is what you want. You can then remove your loop that allocates each individual structure.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing two contradictory things. You have this:

```
Path **array = malloc(items * sizeof(Path *));
```

which does not declare an array of Path structures. It declares an array of pointers to Path structures.

You then have this:

```
for (i=0;i<items;i++) 
{
    array[i] = malloc(Path *); // BUG
}
```

in an attempt to allocate all the structure pointers you need for your array. `malloc(Path *)` is nonsense, and I'm amazed your compiler let you do that. You probably want:

```
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Path));
```

You then have things like this, which are reasonable for an array of pointers to Paths:

```
Path *path = array[id];
path->next_hop=-1;
path->weight=INT_MAX;
```

But your PrintTable() function treats your array as an array of Paths, not an array of pointer to Paths.

@Barmar has just posted the fix for your PrintTable() function, which I won't repeat here.

Your compiler probably warned you about some of these issues.

Comment: Yes that was a mistake. I have sizeof(Path *) in my code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is the tendency to "know" what you're doing and tell the compiler that you want something that doesn't make sense...

```
array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Path *)); // space for a pointer where a struct is needed
```

Get used to a better syntax:

```
array[i] = malloc( sizeof *array[0] );
```

Allocate enough space to store an instance of what the pointer will be pointing at.

(Much less maintenance and fewer bugs caused by naming an incorrect datatype.)